# Travel insurance for jewellery and electronics

Tags: insurance

I want to do some long-term digital-nomad traveling, and one thing I don't know what to do about is how to insure my wife's engagement ring, or our laptop computers, phones, and cameras.

I'm specifically concerned with theft from the AirBnB or hotels, or muggings. That would be unlikely, but a very big loss to absorb, and hence a good use case for insurance. But currently those things are covered under a special rider of my renters insurance, and I'll be giving that up when we leave.

Are there any options for international travelers?

Comment: I think your home country is relevant, as many insurances only take residents of the country.

Comment: There are some insurers out there if you don’t need cover in your home country eg https://www.worldwideinsure.com/international-single-trip-travel-insurance.htm (no affiliation) Personally, I would consider leaving important valuables like an engagement ring in the safekeeping of a trusted individual eg family member or close friend. You may find its value exceeds that included in standard policies

Comment: @Aganju I'm from Canada

Comment: I found jewelersmutual.com which seems to work, just for the ring though.